# Cryptocurrency arbitrage taxes in India

Tags: taxes, arbitrage

Suppose I buy cryptocurrencies in the U.S. and transfer to my or my parents' wallet in India and sell at a premium and make a profit.

1. Is this profit taxable in India?
2. If so, how is it calculated? Selling price in INR minus buying price in USD to INR = capital gains?

Comment: I'm afraid you should be asking in an Indian financial forum, not a Bitcoin one

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it needs to asked in a local indian forum, not here.